# How to configure Rider F# for ubuntu with autocomplete?

Tags: ubuntu, f#, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm trying to get Intellisense for F# on Ubuntu (20.04) using Rider IDE. Intellisense works for C# but not F#, I have tried dotnet 5 and 6 via snap and mono for 4.8.x but neither of them seem to be giving me intellisense suggestions.

F# interactive is also not available in Rider. It is available in the terminal though.

Any ideas on how I can get a better F# experience on ubuntu?

Rider linux not showing types.

[image: Figure shows syntax highlighting but no autocomplete]

Rider windows showing types.

[image: Rider windows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect you are running into a known issue with Snap and FSAC: https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete/issues/654

Try [installing .Net 6 manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual) and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: I was unable to remedy my current machine. Not sure what was wrong, but I started a VirtualMachine using microsoft dot net and ubuntu 21.10 stock and it worked.